# Make a Jar File an Application

Tags: java, jar

How do I make a jar file an application? Like, when(on any OS) you right-click, then selected open with. Jar files, so far as I know, don't do that. They act as a file, not an application. How do I make a jar act as an application? Like, when I want to open a file with my jar, it won't do it - it sees the jar as a file, not an application.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course.

Your jar need to have a META-INF folder and in this folder you must create a file with name "MANIFEST.MF" with this kind of content :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Created-By: 1.4.1_01 (Sun Microsystems Inc.) 
Main-Class: Start 
Class-Path: ./archive1.jar ./archive2.jar
```

The main class must be fully qualifed (com.foo.bar.MainClass).

You can automatically create it with any IDE. In eclipse, right clic on your project > Export > Java > Runnable JAR file, then select your launch configuration and enter a destination jar file.

If you want more information you can read the java tutorials from Oracle : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html